# If a production line is achieving 50% efficiency until 8 days out of 24 working days. how much efficiency they how to achieve each day to reach 70%??

Tags: probability

I want a formula to calculate the efficiency every day a production line has to achieve 70% efficienct in the remaining 16 days in the 24 days working month. If the current efficiency is 50% in the 8 worked days.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple linear equation $\frac{1}{3}*0,5+\frac{2}{3}x=0,7$